# How to give dynamic edgeLength for each node in Cytoscape.js?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am using a concentric layout with number of nodes and if i want to give edgeLength for each node dynamically. How will i be able to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Edge length is a function of layout.  Use a layout that allows you to specify edge length.  Typically, those are physics simulation layouts.

Comment: As i am using a cose layout, the edgeLength function is working for all the nodes at once, but i need to make each edge length dynamically(based on the value i am sending from the db). I tried with concentric and circle layout also but same thing is happening. Any solutions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the functions, just like in the example args for the layout